# How can I enable the wifi connection on HP Pavilion Notebook 8216 83.13?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I can't find the wifi option in my Ubuntu system.

```
$ iwconfig 
lo     no wireless extensions
eno1   no wireless extensions
```

I have tried:

1. Installing new Ubuntu updates. (This only enabled bluetooth access)
2. Tried additional-drivers: it has NVIDIA updates only.
3. I read somewhere to check `rfkill list all` command and it shows results for bluetooth only. So I couldn't do anything further
4. I disabled secure boot, no change

Hardware:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -iA3 net
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:8216]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
```

Comment: @zanna 
1. i installed new ubuntu updates. (This only enabled bluetooth access)
2. Tried additional-drivers: it has NVIDIA updates only.
3. I read somewhere to check 'rfkill list all' command and it is resulting in bluetooth only. so i couldn't do anything further.

Comment: @Zanna - I don't really think he has tried every possible solution, I think he is saying every possible solution he has researched or considered.   Also I am guessing English is not,  possibly,  his first language -  'every ways',  - so maybe we give him some slack?

Comment: @zanna i have listed my tries in above comment. if you want, i can share my team viewer as well.

Comment: @zanna  please see edited question. Are these info enough?

Comment: @Zanna - I was simply pointing out that is a bit early to say it is a hopeless case based on the phrase 'every ways provided on the internet' which you interpreted as 'every possible solution' so language skills play a big part in providing information and understanding this plays a big part in providing solutions

Comment: It will help your solution if you actually enter the commands and provide the information that people request, in order to help you as @Zanna is trying to do

Comment: Have you checked that bios secure boot is disabled as this solution worked for me when no wireless network appeared.

Comment: @kerry i dont know hot to  checked that bios secure boot is disabled or not. As i have seen ubuntu for first time just today, and first thing i am trying is to enable wifi.

Comment: To see BIOS/UEFI options you can usually press a key when booting your computer, like F1 F2 or F12 or del or esc.

Comment: You need to check for your computer how to get into bios options, on mine it is to press esc during boot but as Zanna says it can also be other keys.  You probably need to Google your computer brand/model and how to access bios settings, but checking secure boot would be my first option based on what you have told us

Comment: @zanna sorry for late reply, actually my dual boot option somehow crashed. Anyway, i have checked my bois settings and SECURE BOOT is enabled there. So that is not actually the problem right? Any further assistance is appreciated please.

Comment: @kerry SECURE BOOT is enabled in BIOS menu.

Comment: Ah well done. You may need to disable secure boot, as kerry mentioned

Comment: @zanna i have disabled secure boot, but still there is no option for any kind of wifi. :(

Comment: yeah I think your system is lacking the driver. I don't know how to fix it, but hopefully there is enough information that one of the wireless driver experts will have advice for you. Please add computer information to your question - is it a very new device?

Comment: @zanna  yes, i have purchased it 3 months before.  and also, i run below command :     sky@sky:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

Comment: thanks, that clarifies the problem. What is the make & model?

Comment: @zanna Product Name: HP Pavilion Notebook
Product Name: 8216
        Version: 83.13

Comment: Thanks!!! @wildman that was the exact problem!! THank uoi wildman, **zanna** and **kerry** for helping me out!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Aakash Patel- what is the actual link that wildman helped you with - I would like to know - but dont understand why trying to help gained me 2 down votes - with no explanation - sad world!!!

Comment: Awesome that you got it fixed Aakash :) @kerry you can see the linked post at the top of the question - if it's not clear feel free to ask

Answer (score -1):

ensure index of packages/drivers up to date

```
sudo apt update
```

update Ubuntu PCI IDs

```
sudo update-pciids
```

find your driver and then

```
sudo apt install (package name)
```

in my case for my broadcom wireless adapter

```
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

but the BIG problem, with a simple solution was to ensure that in bios 'secure boot' was DISABLED, otherwise no wireless network options appeared and sometimes for some reason bios reset to enabled so I had to check 'secure boot' was disabled.  If you have tried all the previous solutions then I would check the secure boot option is disabled.

Comment: you have mentioned to find drivers. How to do that?

Comment: Secure Boot is disabled now, but no wifi option is available yet.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote with an answer that actually worked for me, sometimes I wonder why I bother ..... Maybe you can tell me why the down vote....

Comment: Of course we appreciate you wanting to contribute and share your knowledge. I think the reason for downvoting is that you answered without having enough information. Wifi problems are hardware specific, so you need to establish the details first. You can't assume what worked for you will work on a different device. In this case, it seems your answer doesn't help with this particular issue so it doesn't really belong here. There is nothing personal about downvotes, they just indicate, in the voter's opinion, an incorrect or unhelpful answer.